# div show active state when slider on corresponding slide

Tags: jquery, slider, custom-data-attribute

Hi I am trying to get my slider to show its corresponding buttons active state when the slide shows. so if slide one is showing button one should show its active state. if slide two is showing button 2 should show the active state.

So far I have:

```
<!--Top Level Buttons-->
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="colm span_1_of_4">
                <a class="sliderlinks" id="active" href="maritime.html" data-id="1"><h2>Maritime Security</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="colm span_1_of_4">
                <a class="sliderlinks" id="active" href="land.html" data-id="2"><h2>Land Security</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="colm span_1_of_4">
                <a class="sliderlinks" id="active" href="aviation.html" data-id="3"><h2>Aviation Security</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="colm span_1_of_4">
                <a class="sliderlinks" id="active" href="training.html" data-id="4"><h2>Training</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the slide is then below it with this code:

```
<!--Slider-->
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_12_of_12">
                <div class="flexslider">
                  <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/maritime4.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/land1.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/aviation1.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/training1.jpg" />
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My script then looks like this:

```
<!--Slider Jquery-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
            <script>
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            after: function (e) {
                var elem = $(e.target);

                // Retrive the data attribute from the current li
                var box = elem.attr('data-id');

                // First unset all of the current boxes from being active
                $('.sliderlinks').removeid('active');

                // Append the data attribute value from the li to a class (one of the li's) and set the
                // class to be active
                $('.sliderlinks'+box).addid('active');
            }
          });
            </script>
```

I cant work out what im doing wrong, im in a muddle, can someone please help me out :)

Thank you in advance

Lee

Comment: ids should be unique so you should move the active to the class and the use removeClass or addClass

Comment: Hi Pete, thank you, I have changed my id's to classes, but it still doesn't help with how to make the corresponding button light up when its  slide appears.